# Xamarin.Android - Hide Content in App Preview

Tags: xamarin.android

I would like to hide content of my android app in the app preview mode. I am referring to the view you see when switching between apps.

The following window settings hides the content but it also disables the ability to take screenshots of the app which I don't want

```
activity.Window.SetFlags(WindowManagerFlags.Secure, WindowManagerFlags.Secure);
```

Is there a setting I could use to hide the app content but still allow the user to take screen shots?

Here is an example of the app preview where the content isn't hidden

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For platforms Android 8.0 and newer(>= SDK 26), to make the screen blank in recent list and still allow screen you can set the flag in onPause() and clear the flag in onResume().
To make it common for all activities, in Application class register an Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks and add following lines inside specific overridden functions. You may try this:

```
fun onActivityResumed(activity: Activity) {
activity?.window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
}

fun onActivityPaused(activity: Activity) {
activity?.window?.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
}
```

Comment: I tried onActivityPaused and onActivityPrePaused to set the flag. It seems that I am too late and Android has already taken an app snapshot to show in the preview. The app content is visible in the preview unless I switch back and fourth between my app and some other app a couple of times. Eventually the preview is updated with the "no-content" preview

Comment: If I set the Secure flag in OnActivityCreated the content is hidden first time in send the app into the background. Is there a way to force an app preview refresh ?

Comment: When do you want to force the application preview refresh? Is it the time to switch back and forth between your application and other applications?

Comment: On Pause or PrePause, when I set the Secure flag I would like to somehow update the preview screen shown during app switching.

Comment: Essentially, I would like to somehow update what the app switcher shows so the content is actually obfuscated. Android does update when I switch back and forth between apps but this is too late

Comment: Could you consider setting something in the OnRestart method?